# When installing coc-java, coc cannot define java environment

Tags: java, neovim, java-21

I have installed coc for neovim, after that I ran the command to install coc-java:

```
:CocInstall coc-java
```

Then configured `coc-settings.json` which is in `~/.config/nvim` folder:

```json
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
      {
        "name": "JavaSE-21",
        "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-21.0.2",
        "default": true
      }
    ]
```

The jdk is truly lying at the path above, however, Coc spits this error when opening a java file:

```
Invalid runtime for JavaSE-21: Runtime at '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-21.0.2' is not compatible with the 'JavaSE-21' environment.
```

I'm following the original [tutorial](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-java#:%7E:text=minimum%20required%20version.-,Project%20JDKs,-If%20you%20need) of the author of coc-java on how to set up an environment. I'm using neovim as the text editor, please help me solve it

Comment: What does this have to do with `[liskov-substitution-principle]`?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally added that tag

Comment: Well ... it looks like nobody >here< knows the answer.  So I suggest you try one of the "Feedback" options mentioned in the README.md.  See https://github.com/neoclide/coc-java?tab=readme-ov-file#feedback